# How do I get apache to access another drive in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, drives

Basically I've nearly run out of space on the drive that Apache is installed on (my server is running Ubuntu desktop 15.04, 32-bit). I've tried to keep everything in the /www/html/ folder but there's no more room. However, I have a spare drive that I can store stuff on. I've searched for ages and everyone's saying "you can't access other drives like that, be thankful it can't because -insert security issue-", which is absolutely stupid because I doubt every server in the world has only one drive per server. Naturally you need to distribute the files on many disks. The main question is how do I get my server to use my other drive as well? Do I make a shortcut to the drive and put it in /www/html/ and then specify the directory in my html files as "/www/html/drive2/..."?
Sorry if I sound stupid, I'm still new to running my own server (which is basically just a spare computer I had in my closet).

Comment: How about symlinking a folder in the other drive inside `/www/html`? Have you tried that?

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. So to understand it entirely, basically I just run "cd /var/www/html/
ln -sv /media/drive2/folder/" and it creates a link that will allow me to follow to "folder" on drive 2?

Comment: yeah, permissions might be tricky, but nothing that can't be solved

Comment: I keep getting an error 403. Am I doing something wrong?